# Download file from website with selenium on Python 2.7.5. File changes part of a name daily (date is part of file's name)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have following problem. I am trying to script downloading file, which is being daily uploaded on a website. file name is "My Report $date.xlsx" (so Today it's "My Report 20190917.xlsx).

The only value that is constant is title of it, actually part of it without the date. hastooltip and href are changing.

Here is the code I need to use:

```
<a class="entry-title" rel="bookmark" title="My Report 20190917.xlsx" href="https://xxxx/foo/bar/something.html" hastooltip="dijit_Tooltip_10400"><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr><wbr>My Report 20190917.xlsx</a>
```

And here is what I have googled/ tried so far, I think this is very near:

[selenium find element by title that contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011212/selenium-find-element-by-title-that-contains?rq=1)

I tried using same thing with xpath instead of css_selector, but no luck (title^= instead of title=: )

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='list']/div[@role='region']/table[@role='presentation']/tbody/tr[15]//a[title^='My Report']").click()
```

I also tried using some options like "title contains" and tried to use variable instead of 'My Report' name like:

```
import time
my_file =("My Report " +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".xlsx")
```

and putting my_file variable into the xpath search, but that did not work at all.

Shortly I am out of ideas and kindly asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a possible solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
exp = "//*[@title='My Report "+today+".xlsx']"

myfile = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,(" %s" % exp))
myfile.click()
```

I hope it helps

I believe you are working with a content not availble online. So, I cannot try it.
The expression I gave you return this:

```
Element='<a class="entry-title"
hastooltip="dijit_Tooltip_10400"
href="https://xxxx/foo/bar/something.html"
rel="bookmark"
title="My Report 20190917.xlsx"/>'
```

But what you actually need is the path to the xls.
If the link for the xls is the href above, you can do this:

```
myfile.get_attribute('href')
```

I don't know if it's enough to do the download or if you have to open by command:

```
driver.get(myfile.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: After using that code I got the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string ' My Report 20190917.xlsx' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: I tried using options with variables, but I am not sure if sellenium for python 2.7.5 is able to recognize that, anyways thanks for trying.

Comment: What happens if you print myfile.get_attribute('innerText')?

Comment: I cannot print it, due to not valid xpath expression. Here is entire error, hope that helps:

Comment: not full log:
  File "./download_My.py", line 68, in <module>
    myfile = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,("%s" % exp))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression My Report 20190917.xlsx because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'My Report 20190917.xlsx' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the expression exp should be: exp    = "//*[@title='My Report "+today+".xlsx']"

Comment: It looks better, but now I have this - obviously I have to click this document to download it (?)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./download_My.py", line 66, in <module>
    myfile.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

And here is the code now:


today = datetime.now()
today = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
exp = "//*[@title='My Report "+today+".xlsx']"
myfile = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,("%s" % exp))
myfile.click()

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  date_time_now = datetime.now()
  my_string = "My Report "+date_time_now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='entry-title' and starts-with(@title, '" + my_string + "')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```